# Есть ли ошибки в этом сообщении (стилистика, пунктуация и т. д.)

Tags: грамотная-речь

**[Из статьи о погоде](https://%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5):**

*Синоптик рассказал об аномально холодной погоде в России. По его словам, это связано с антициклоном, который стоит над Якутией.*

*«Там область высокого давления. В то же время на северо-востоке Урала стоит циклон. Там качает холодный воздух. Стоит тёплый циклон у нас в районе Стокгольма и практически во всей Европе тепло идёт», — отметил он.*

Есть ли **ошибки** и какие?  Как бы **вы записали** этот текст?